Связь anchor и :focus
Встретился такой метод создания footnotes. В основном тексте:
bla-bla <a id="fn-1" href="#1">1</a> 

В подвале:
<a id="1" href="#fn-1">1</a> explain bla-bla

Но когда его используешь в Firefox, последний задействованный анкор подсвечен
прям и тенью, и контуром.
Я гуглил по запросам "visited, anchor, link, style", и вроде бы везде обсуждается похожая проблема. Предлагаются разные решения, но они не работают.
Совершенно случайно догадался почитать про :focus. Задействовал такой метод:
a:focus {
    outline: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

и он заработал!
Вопросы такие: почему нигде не описана связь anchor и :focus?
И не повлияет ли такое решение на какое-то другое поведение ссылок и элементов?
Сайтик очень простой, типа записной книжки, но все же.

Ну так вы ссылаетесь с ссылки на ссылку, а ссылка включает автофокус(точнее стили установленны на тег ) как и input. Если ссылку на input сделать, он активным станет и можно будет писать не выделяя мышкой это поле.

Даже можете проверить и не на ссылке. сделайте одну из них просто  и задайте #fn-1:focus {color:red} например и когда перейдёте, хоть он и не ссылка, он перекрасится в красный.

@ЕвгенийЛи, а где об этом "ссылка включает автофокус" ну как-то теоретически подробно что-ли написано?

У меня просто нет задачи "любой ценой чего-то добиться", а хочется понимать как все работает, какие-подводные камни

а без понятия, это то, что приходит с опытом думаю)

@DenisIvanov :focus может быть только у интерактивных элементов. То что происходит в вашем случае - это :target. Что бы понять что конкретно случилось вам нужно посмотреть через devtools на рабочий код.

@AndreiFedorov, да уж, как-то запутался. :target никак не влияет на box и outline. Попробую через devtools. Но хотелось бы конечно что-то серьезное почитать на эту тему, не просто описание в mdn.
